# Adding colours to table rows in a pdf generated bt fpdf.php

Tags: php, pdf, colors, fpdf

The following code in php is used by me to generate a pdf which contains tables!
I want to add colours to the table rows! What is the method that I can use to add colours to the table rows?

```
<?php
require("../../db/db.php"); //provides database connection

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");


class PDF extends FPDF{
function Header(){

$this->setFont('Arial','B',14);
$this->Image("logo.png");    

$this->ln(20);
}



}

$sql="SELECT count(Email) as Number, Date from reportorder";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

$pdf->Cell(90,10,'Date',1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->Cell(90,10,'Number of orders',1,1,'C',0);


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

  // cell with left and right borders

$pdf->Cell(90,10,$row['Date'],1,0,'C',0); // 1,0 
$pdf->Cell(90,10,$row['Number'] ,1,1,'C',0);


}

$pdf->output();


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to set your fill color:

```
//RGB colors 0-255, param order is r,g,b you can google RGB colors
//change 100,100,100 to be whatever color you want
$pdf->SetFillColor(100,100,100);
```

Now flip on the boolean in your Cell to use the fill:

```
//parameter list for reference
$pdf->Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])

//sample of the heading with use fill boolean fliped (the 1 after the 'C')
$pdf->Cell(90,10,'Date',1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell(90,10,'Number of orders',1,1,'C',true);
```

To change colors, just run $pdf->SetFillColor again.

Comment: when i put this  $pdf->Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]]) i get unexpected "w"

Comment: that's the parameter list..... float w, put 90, float h, put 10, string txt put your out put string, etc. what you really care about is flipping the boolean switch after your align 'C' see the 2 lines of code below that parameter list.

Comment: yeah but i didnt get any colour

Comment: did put in the $pdf->SetFillColor(100,100,100); before your $pdf->Cell call? Did you flip the use fill parameter? It should generate a dark grey background, you can try changing 'C', 1) to 'C', true) in the cell call

Comment: yeah thanx now it works smoothly how can i change the colour to light blue?

Comment: Here's a [RGB Color Code Chart](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) that'll help you generate any color you want.

Comment: Thank you very much